# How to register and start glassfish 7.0.9 from netbeans 19 IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, java-21

I have done a fresh installation of JDK 21 installed Netbeans 19 IDE.
`java --version` gives the output `java 21 2023-09-19 LTS Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21+35-LTS-2513) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21+35-LTS-2513, mixed mode, sharing)` 
In then I started netbeans and created a new project > servers clicked add server > then from the list I can only see chose netbeans 7.0.6 as the latest version. But my I had already downloaded glassfish 7.0.9 and netbeans can see detect it from the glassfish directory so I click next to add. Problem is that netbeans still sees it as glassfish 7.0.6. When i try to run my project I get an error `Could not find Java SE Development Kit to start GlassFish Server,`But in the `glassfish/bin` directory I can start glassfish with the command `./asadmin start-domain domain1`

How do I properly register glassfish 7.0.9 to netbeans and is it even supported. I have also confirmed that the JDK platform is properly added as shown in the attached image. [image]

In summary I have tried all versions of glassfish 7.x.x in netbeans. I have downloaded a stand alone instance and tried to register it to netbeans. I downgraded to netbeans 18 with jdk 17 and followed the same exact steps and the server worked.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**:

You can't start GlassFish 7.0.9 within NetBeans 19 when running JDK 21. That combination is simply not supported. As you have discovered, the most recent GlassFish release that NetBeans 19 supports is GlassFish 7.0.6 when using JDK +21.

**Solution:**

<strike>Wait for the next quarterly release of NetBeans, which will almost certainly support GlassFish 7.0.9 and JDK 21.</strike>

Wait for the next quarterly release of NetBeans (NetBeans 20), which will support GlassFish 7.0.9 and JDK 21. NetBeans Bug Report [Add support for GlassFish 7.0.7, 7.0.8, and 7.0.9 #6542](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/6542) documents this planned enhancement.

**Workaround**:

As you point out, you can run GlassFish 7.0.9 outside of NetBeans 19, and manually deploy your applications to the GlassFish server via its Admin Console. That's tedious, but straightforward, and may be appropriate since there have been quite a few fixes and enhancements since GlassFish 7.0.6.

**Explanation**:

These are the release dates for the software products you are using:

- NetBeans 19 was released on September 1, 2023.
- JDK 21 was released on September 19, 2023.
- GlassFish 7.0.9 was released on September 29, 2023.

That's a lot of cutting edge technology. To state the obvious, NetBeans 19 necessarily cannot be expected to offer formal support for products released after its own release date, because those products cannot have been fully tested. Therefore, NetBeans 19 does not formally support JDK 21 or GlassFish 7.0.9. From the [Release Notes for NetBeans 19](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb19/):

> *The Apache NetBeans 19 binary releases require JDK 11+, and officially
> support running on JDK 11, 17 and 20*.

Similarly, [GlassFish 7.0.9 is not formally supported under JDK 21](https://glassfish.org/download.html), and its Release Notes explicitly state that:

> *This release prepares GlassFish for the upcoming JDK 21; it compiles
> and passes all internal tests using OpenJDK 21ea35. Several TCKs
> passed on JDK 21 as well, but the TCK as a whole is not JDK 21
> compatible yet.*

So even if NetBeans 19 did support GlassFish 7.0.9, GlassFish itself might not work, and definitely would not be supported, when using JDK 21.

Notes:

- The readme for GlassFish 7.0.6 states: *"Eclipse GlassFish 7.0.9 requires JDK 11 or newer."*. Based on its own Release Notes I think that's misleading/wrong, and it should instead state *"Eclipse GlassFish 7.0.9 requires a JDK between JDK 11 and JDK 20."*.
- There is a distinction between software releases not being supported and software releases not being permitted. For example, NetBeans 19 does not formally support JDK 21, but you can still use it at your own risk. In contrast, NetBeans 19 explicitly prevents you from using any GlassFish release > 7.0.6, and the GlassFish 7.0.9 documentation explicitly disallows the use of JDK 21.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Although Netbeans 19 officially supports only GlassFish 7.0.6, it also works well with GlassFish 7.0.9 without issues, unless you're using Java 21. If you use Java 20 or older, Netbeans works with GlassFish 7.0.9. However, Netbeans allows to select a JDK to run GlassFish, and it allows to use only JDK 11-20 with GlassFish. The next release of Netbeans will support GlassFish on Java 21 too: https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/6542. GlassFish runs well on Java 21, the release notes only states that the full TCK cannot run on Java 21, only a subset of it.

Comment: @OndroMih As far as I can tell all the information in your comment is repeating what was already provided in my answer, and I was careful to distinguish between officially supported use and combinations that might work. What did I write that is _"not entirely true"_?

Comment: HI, maybe I misunderstood. But you wrote:
"NetBeans explicitly prevents you from using any GlassFish release > 7.0.6, and the GlassFish 7.0.9 documentation explicitly disallows the use of JDK 21.". This is not true. Netbeans 19 actually allows you to use GlassFish 7.0.9 with Java 19 or older, it just reports it's a 7.0.6 version. Netbeans 19 doesn't permit to run any GlassFish version with Java 21, even 7.0.6. And if you look at https://glassfish.org/download_gf7.html, you'll see that GlassFish runs on Java 21, just some tests don't run on Java 21.

Comment: @OndroMih OK, no you didn't misunderstand, and I have edited my answer to change some references to _"NetBeans"_ to _"NetBeans 21"_ for accuracy and clarity. But with respect to GlassFish 7.0.9 running on JDK 21, I'm going by the GlassFish documentation which states (from your link) _"the TCK as a whole is not JDK 21 compatible yet"_. I interpret that to imply that GlassFish 7.0.9 is not currently supported under JDK 21. (How can it be? Some tests not running on JDK21 is not a trivial issue.) However, if that's not the case then the documentation needs to be updated to clarify the situation.

Comment: I agree, GlassFish documentation isn't clear. But the whole Jakarta EE TCK cannot be executed on Java 21, because some tests require Java features dropped in Java 21. That doesn't mean that GlassFish doesn't run or isn't supported on Java 21. It only means that it cannot be certified as Jakarta EE 10 server with Java 21. GlassFish runs just fine on Java 21, it can even be compiled with Java 21, it's just not documented very well.

Comment: I asked the GlassFish team to update the documentation. It now says GlassFish 7.0.9 "compiles and runs on JDK 11 to JDK 21".

Comment: @OndroMih Yes, I see that change, and I think I now understand the situation. Also, FYI I have updated the _Solution_ section of my answer since there is [new NetBeans Bug Report #6542](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/6542) which confirms that support for the latest versions of the JDK and GlassFish will be included in NetBeans 20., due for release in the second half of November.