# Configuring GlassFish Server for External Project in Netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I have a project that I downloaded the source code and imported it into my Netbeans IDE version 17. It is a web application built using Java, Java Servlets and JSP and database uses MySQL. The project is supposed to run on GlassFish Server. I already have the latest version of  GlassFish server(7.0.0) installed in my netbeans IDE. Upon opening the project I am getting this error: One or more projects do not have the target server set properly. Right-click the project in the Projects window and choose Resolve Missing Server Problem to set the target server.

After following the steps listed in the error message I get another error: Not a Valid GlassFish Server installation

Comment: You forgot to tell which project exactly it is and/or which server version it actually requires. One possible cause would be that it's written with GlassFish 5.0 in mind. Such a project is then indeed not compatible with GlassFish 6.0 or newer due to incompatible changes in JEE package names.

Comment: Though not a duplicate, [How to register and start glassfish 7.0.9 from netbeans 19 IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77210369/2985643) may be relevant and helpful. But your question cannot be meaningfully answered without knowing which JDK you are using, so update it accordingly. Also note that [GlassFish 7.0.0 _"...runs on JDK 11 to JDK 19"_](https://glassfish.org/download_gf7.html), so if you are using a JDK > 19 you must either downgrade your JDK, or upgrade GlassFish. Ideally, upgrade to GlassFish 7.0.10 if possible, since that is the latest release, and _"runs on JDK 11 to JDK 21"_.